# How to set NoDelay socket option

Tags: supersocket.net

How to set `NoDelay` socket option (or socket options in general) with [supersocket](https://supersocket.codeplex.com/)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok that was easy, don't know why I didn't see it before.
Underlying `Socket` object is accessible through session.

```
WebSocketServer appServer;
appServer.NewSessionConnected += session => 
                                 session.SocketSession.Client
                                 .SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.Socket, 
                                                 SocketOptionName.NoDelay, true);
```